# How to restart app (react native and expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I use expo so I've no access to android folder.

I want to restart my app for first time. How can I do that?

I use [react-native-restart](https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart/), but not wroking and I have an error now:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'x.default.restart;)

Codes:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (I18nManager.isRTL) {
      I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
      RNRestart.Restart();
    }
  }
```

How Can I restart my app?

Comment: You can use `react-native-code-push`

Comment: @hongdevelop Can you send an answer? I can't find any related command in documentation...

Comment: this issue wraps the problem: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10598 . TL:DR - `import { reloadAsync } from "expo-updates"; setTimeout(async () => await reloadAsync(), 100);`

Comment: I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had the same problem for over a month, nothing helped me, so I developed a library to accomplish this, simple install it using:

```
npm i fiction-expo-restart
```

and import it like:

```
import {Restart} from 'fiction-expo-restart';
```

and then when you want to perform a restart, use:

```
Restart();
```

Note in case this answer gets old, you can check the library here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fiction-expo-restart

Comment: @oroncohen how? can you please explain? this library still works, if you can make a expo snack, I can fix your issue

Comment: there's no source code openly available for this lib. I don't install anything that I can't read its code... Although, @oroncohen opened a feature request to expo: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-react-native-restart-support - vote if you need it

Comment: I'm making it publicly available today. I didn't even notice this.

Comment: It just calls Updates.reloadAsync. That don't work on my expo app.

Comment: @AliMertCakar well, it works for others. let me help you if you still didn't find any solution, ping me at mahevstark@gmail.com

Comment: I've figured it out, turns out i had a typo.

Comment: Source code is here (https://github.com/mahevstark/fiction-expo-restart). The link still needs to get added on npmjs.com.

Answer (score 11):

I have faced the same issue and found this solution somewhere.

You can try to use `Updates` from `expo` like this:

```js
import { Updates } from 'expo';

Updates.reload();
```

Comment: I think I can't use 'Updates' because I disabled it and I don't want to check updates. Right?

Comment: this answer no longer works from SDK v37 - https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-37-is-now-available-dd5770f066a6#858a . `Updates.reload()` is no longer there, and `Updates.reloadAsync()` doesn't seem to be triggered if there's no update.

Comment: ok, so the problem was not the availability of new updates, but the fact that `Updates.reloadAsync()` in my case was fired too close to app initialization. The temporary workaround is to wrap it in some timeout, the issue to follow up is here - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10598

Comment: Looks like it's not working anymore with the new expo sdk's (45+), Instead: 
import { reloadAsync } from 'expo-updates';
reloadAsync()

Answer (score 3):

For Expo SDK 45+ please use

```js
import * as Updates from "expo-updates"
Updates.reloadAsync()
```

The module `fiction-expo-restart` is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { Button, I18nManager, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import * as Updates from "expo-updates";

async function toggleRTL() {
  await I18nManager.forceRTL(I18nManager.isRTL ? false : true);
  await Updates.reloadAsync();
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{new Date().toString()}</Text>
      <Text>{I18nManager.isRTL ? "RTL" : "LTR"}</Text>
      <View style={{ marginVertical: 5 }} />
      <Button title="Reload app" onPress={() => Updates.reloadAsync()} />
      <View style={{ marginVertical: 5 }} />
      <Button title="Toggle RTL" onPress={() => toggleRTL()} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

https://github.com/brentvatne/updates-reload/blob/master/App.js
It's the only working way for me. When i try automatically reload app in useEffect - it crashes, so i make a separate screen where i ask user to press button to reload app

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`react-native-code-push`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-code-push) library, you can restart with this;

```
import CodePush from 'react-native-code-push';
CodePush.restartApp();
```

Comment: Error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'A.default.restartApp')`

Comment: did you link it

Comment: I use yarn to install this package. Is this need to link?

Comment: Code push won't work if you do not have any bundle release on AppCenter and may crash on release build. use RNRestart package!

Comment: OP states specifically that Expo is used. There's no linking possible in Expo, so packages that require linking won't work

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to build a **Restart** component that is not a `const` but a `var`. And an `applyReload()` function that sets that var to an empty component `<></>` if the `reload` bool state is true, triggering the re-render.

The re-render will reinstate the **Restart** `var` back to its original structure, but a new instance is then created, effectively reloading everything that is inside the `<Restart>` tag:

My App.tsx:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

  type Props = { children: ReactNode };
  var Restart = ({ children }: Props) => {
    return <>{children}</>;
  };
  const applyReload = () => {
    if (reload) {
      Restart = ({ children }: Props) => {
        return <></>;
      };
      setReload(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(applyReload);

  useEffect(() => {
    // put some code here to modify your app..

    // test reload after 6 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      setReload(true);
    }, 6000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <PaperProvider theme={appTheme}>
          <NavigationContainer theme={appTheme} documentTitle={{ enabled: false }}>
            <AppContext.Provider value={appContext}>
              <Restart>
                <MyMainAppComponent />
              </Restart>
            </AppContext.Provider>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </PaperProvider>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
```

I also added the 'setReload' state function to my '<AppContext.Provider>' so anywhere down my App it is possible to trigger the App reload.