# React-Native image localization

Tags: react-native, expo, localization, assets

this question will be more of a how to question.

Task:

- I would need to localise an already existing mobile application, for this using expo-localization and i84n dependencies (these parts are okay)
- The mobile app would need to be available in multiple countries with localised assets as well including images, and possibly country selection.

Initially i thought i would just implement a screen with country selection and based on that changing the localisation in app and assets, but after doning some digging around dynamic image imports and country selection etc.. it did not seem to be straight forward which made me think if im trying to take the right approach here?

Could someone point me to references which would fit my use case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already made the country selection screen,  using I18nManager.forceRTL(true), the Core of react native will switch start from left to right and end from right to left.
Using I18nManager.
forceRTL(false) will return it back to its original setting.
you will need to restart the app after RTL support country is being chosen using [fiction-expo-restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330046/how-to-restart-app-react-native-and-expo) then
Then check the image importing like this:

```
let image = require('./left.png');
if (I18nManager.isRTL) {
  image = require('./right.png');
}
```

also check this [Blog](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps)